# Who introduced the term "the Northern Thing" for fantasy works inspired by Germanic mythology?

Tags: history-of, fantasy-genre, quotes, terminology

The works particularly of Tolkien and some other writers like Robert Howard and Poul Anderson are sometimes described as being influenced by "that Northern Thing", meaning mythology and medieval tales of the Germanic peoples of northern Europe.

Who introduced that expression and in what context and for what purpose was it used?

Comment: Are you sure it's a "thing" and not just some phrase made up by a few acquaintances of yours? Edit the question to provide some evidence.

Comment: While evidence would be helpful, a simple google suggests that "That Northern Thing" is, in fact, a thing.  However, I wonder if "thing" refers not to a general indistinct "thing" but rather "[thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thing_(assembly))", the old English/Norse/Germanic term for an assembly.

Comment: I mean this thing: [The Whole Northern Thing](https://www.blackgate.com/2013/12/03/the-whole-northern-thing-hrolf-krakis-saga-by-poul-anderson/), [Howard vs. De Camp](http://www.gwthomas.org/howardversusdecamp.htm), [Legends - Poets and Painters](http://bestoflegends.org/poets/), [Tolkien, Aulden, ...](https://bookhaven.stanford.edu/2012/12/tolkien-auden-and-an-evening-of-mushrooms-and-elvish/).

Comment: Doesn't the site you linked to in your comment attribute it to W. H. Auden?

Comment: I've also seen it attributed to Tolkien himself and to Lin Carter. Which is why I was wondering if anyone knows of a confirmed source.

Comment: [This *New Yorker* article](http://www.newyorker.com/books/page-turner/auden-and-elvish) also attributes "the whole Northern thing" to Auden.

Comment: Apparently it's quoted directly in [this article](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/1966/01/15/the-elvish-mode) which I can't read because I'm not a subscriber.

Comment: Interesting. I think you could post that as an answer that people can vote on.

Comment: @user14111 I'm a subscriber. I think this is the relevant quote: "'Tolkien is fascinated with the whole Northern thing,' Auden said. 'People seem to divide—they're attracted by either the Northern thing or the Southern thing, by Scandinavia or the Mediterranean—and for Tolkien north is a sacred direction.'" From _The Elvish Mode_, appearing in the January, 15, 1966 issue of _The New Yorker_. Auden made this statement at a talk he gave at a meeting of the Tolkien Society of America.

Comment: @Torisuda Good, why don't you post an answer.

Comment: @user14111 Because it felt a bit like cheating to post an answer without doing any work other than buying a _New Yorker_ subscription ten months ago.

Comment: @Torisuda Does the *New Yorker* article give the date of the meeting where Auden gave that talk?

Comment: @user14111 It doesn't give an exact date, but it says "The other day we walked over", which implies the meeting was sometime in late December 1965 or early January 1966.

Comment: @Torisuda Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The phrase "the [whole] Northern thing" may have its origin in the poet [W. H. Auden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._H._Auden)'s talk "Tolkien as a Man" at a meeting of the [Tolkien Society of America](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Tolkien_Society_of_America) in New York. [Gerald Jonas](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?12202) reported on that meeting in his article ["The Elvish Mode"](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/1966/01/15/the-elvish-mode) in the January 15, 1966, issue of [*The New Yorker*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_Yorker). [Torisuda](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/28578/torisuda), in a [comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/146495/who-introduced-the-term-the-northern-thing-for-fantasy-works-inspired-by-germa#comment374689_146495), kindly provided the following quotation from behind the *New Yorker* paywall:

> "Tolkien is fascinated with the whole Northern thing," Auden said. "People seem to divide—they're attracted by either the Northern thing or the Southern thing, by Scandinavia or the Mediterranean—and for Tolkien north is a sacred direction."